# How to manage multiple concurrent downloads using Service?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

I'm trying to create a download manager inside my application. There might be multiple simultaneous downloads running in the background. I'm going to have an activity in which I gather all the running downloads and show a progress bar and a pause button for each.
This is how I'm gonna do it. Please let me know if I'm doing it wrong.

First of all I'll create a service named `DownloadService` and inside this service there will be an `AsyncTask` class which will do the downloads. I have a method in the service that can start new downloads by firing up the `AsyncTask` class for each call. There will also be an array of `AsyncTask` instances for when I need to access these running tasks and get their progress state.
This is the general idea. Is this the right way?

Comment: I think you should test it yourself. I can try to solve your _detailed-problem_, not this one...

Comment: I'm trying to find the best solution to save the effort of redoing it.

Comment: I'm sorry but SO is place to ask when you can't solve _your problem_, not for solving _your job_. Hope you don't mind about that...

Comment: I'm not asking you to solve anything. Just correct me if I'm wrong. That's all. I don't think this conflicts with SO's terms.

Comment: I think you're doing right. But if you want to keep the service running in background (after the users exited your app), you should use remote service. Because local service will stop if the user exits your app.